# How to use Kali Linux using a pendrive (USB)

Tags: boot, usb, kali-linux

I have got Windows 8.1 installed on my PC.
I have Kali Linux in my pendrive.

I am not able to navigate my self to the boot menu in my Lenovo PC.
If I press <kbd>F12</kbd> it will show me something but not USB option.
And if I press <kbd>F1</kbd> it will go to settings.

Can someone please sortout my problem because I want to use Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like "removable media" is not enabled in your bios settings, try enable it and then retry to display the boot popup.